# Matching between product and customer personal information

Tags: c#, c++, algorithm

I writing some application that find ( according to some question ) information about some person ( lets say that the information are weight, height and age of the person ).

In the other hand i have product list ( can be very big one ) and according to the product information i need to find the best matching between the person information and the product
 ( the product information that i have are water part, nitrogen part and ext. )

I can't use flow chart algorithm or Breadth-first search because the number of the product is dynamically ( read the product list from DB ... )

---

*added more information given as answer*

More information: I have some matching table for each of the product field. I can tell that if the person field_X is with value A => so the product that match is product_1.

This is simple and i can use hash table - but i need the best matching according to all the fields.

Using heuristics can be good in this case - but in case i have some measure all the person fields => and i have also the measure of the product fields ... i can find the best match - but each cycle i have new product and scanning all the product can be hard work and will take time.

I looking ( if there is ) some better way.

Comment: This question is as vague as they get. If you can't give us any more information than that, and if you can't make it clearer, we simply CANNOT help you. Unfortunately, I haven't mastered telepathy yet. :P

Comment: I made mistake and vote to close this question (instead of another one) now how I can cancel this?

Comment: Please tell me what is not clear ?

Comment: You simple have 2 list - first list is persomal information ( contain 3 fields ) and the second list contain product information ( contain 6 fields ). the mission is to fine the best matching between the person information and the product information.

Comment: What are the 6 product fields exactly? Which data types are used? How does the range of possible values for those 9 (3+6) fields look like?

Comment: As far as we can tell, the "best" match might be to give the first customer the first product from the list, the second person the second product, etc. There's no reasonable generic way to solve such a broad class of problems.

Comment: Given the (admittedly vague) description of what you want to achieve, it seems to be in my interest that you fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be very similar to something called ["The Nearest neighbour problem"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search).

Imagine you could turn each field/attribute into a number. Then each person and each product can be represented as a point in an N dimensional space. So if your two attributes were weight and height then you could make the person an (x,y) point with x being the weight and b being the height.

You then have to determine how you define "best". This defines the distance between two points and is called a metric. So the distance between (x1,y1) and (x2,y2) might be (x1-x2)+(y1-y2) for a very simple metric.

Having decided your space and your metric you can use one of the algorithms described on the wikipedia page (linked above) to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need some attributes (according to those of your persons) that allow "matching" products with persons. So, you also need some kind of metric for that. Then you can find the products, which best match a given person with regard to the metric and based on defined attributes. And maybe you can try some Data Mining techniques like support/confidence or so. I don't know, for more detailed advices, you have to provide more information...